# How do I append a single item from one array to a different array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and running into a problem. I have a row containing 'shoeData' in one view and a grid in a different view containing 'extraShoes'. I want the user to have the ability to append an item from 'extraShoes' to the row containing 'shoeData'.

Here are my two arrays:

```
struct AddedShoes: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var image: Image
}
var extraShoes = [
    AddedShoes(title: "Saucony Kinvara 12", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SauconyKinvara"))),
    AddedShoes(title: "Hoka Mach 4", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "HokaMach"))),
    AddedShoes(title: "North Face Vectiv", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NFVectiv"))) ]

struct Shoes: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var image: Image
}
var shoeData = [
    Shoes(title: "Adidas Adios Pro", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AdidasAdiosPro"))),
    Shoes(title: "Nike Pegasus 37", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NikePegs"))),
    Shoes(title: "Hoka Rincon 2", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "HokaRincon"))),
    Shoes(title: "Saucony Endorphin Speed", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SauconySpeed"))),
    Shoes(title: "Nike Next% 2", image: Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NikeNext"))),
```

Here is the grid layout containing extraShoes. I want to add one item from extraShoes to the row containing shoeData in a different view when a user clicks a button.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(extraShoes.filter({"\($0)".contains(searchField) || searchField.isEmpty})) { item in
                            ShoeProfile(card: item)
                        }
                    }
```

Here is the row in a different view.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(shoeData) { item in
                                ShoeCard(runner: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thank you in advance! I'm not sure if I need to make the main view an observable object or a binding. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why would you create a different structure with the same properties?

Comment: A user starts off with the inventory included in shoeData but not every shoe will be utilized in extraShoes. So, if a user let's say purchases a shoe, then they can add the shoe from extraShoes to shoeData. I'm not sure if I'm better off making it into one struct and using a range instead. Any recommendations?

Comment: Still unclear to me why would you need a structure with a different name. Just create separate collections.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I'm still unable to figure out how to add the item to the row. I attempted to put a button within the ForEach but keep getting an error. Any idea?